# Pandas: Grouping DataFrame records into Weekly and Monthly records

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame consisting of these columns: ActualDate, Brand, Likes and Comments. ActualDate contains date values in YYYY-MM-DD format and has got duplicate values. Brand is a string while likes and comments are integer values. I wish to aggregate this data into weekly and monthly formats showing average for likes and comments. I tried the following code but faced some issues. Please help.

```
df_output['ActualDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_output['ActualDate'])
print(df_output.head(30))
df_output_weekly = pd.DataFrame()
df_output_weekly=df_output.reset_index().set_index('ActualDate').resample("W")
df_output.set_index(df_output['ActualDate'])
print(df_output_weekly.head())
```

Comment: share df_output.head()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need add `mean`:

```
df_output['ActualDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_output['ActualDate'])

df_output_weekly= df_output.set_index('ActualDate').resample("W").mean().reset_index()
print(df_output_weekly.head())
```

Sample:

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame({'ActualDate':['2016-01-02','2016-01-03','2016-01-04'],
                          'Brand':['s','d','f'],
                          'Likes':[7,8,9],
                          'Comments':[7,8,9]})

print (df_output)
   ActualDate Brand  Comments  Likes
0  2016-01-02     s         7      7
1  2016-01-03     d         8      8
2  2016-01-04     f         9      9

df_output['ActualDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_output['ActualDate'])

df_output_weekly= df_output.set_index('ActualDate').resample("W").mean().reset_index()
print(df_output_weekly.head())
  ActualDate  Comments  Likes
0 2016-01-03       7.5    7.5
1 2016-01-10       9.0    9.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I came up with the below but your suggestion seems more elegant. Thanks! 
    df_output_weekly=df_output.reset_index().set_index('ActualDate').resample("W").agg({'Likes':np.mean,'Comments':np.mean})